# SharePoint List View Web Part Column Filtering options

Tags: list-view, xslt

By default, filtering options for each column in a SharePoint List View Web Part are sorted alphabetically. Meaning, if there is a list and three list items with the following titles A, B & C, when you click on the column Title for sorting, the values shown will be in that same order "A", "B" & "C".

What I would like is to change the sorting criteria for these optons, and show the value of the newest item first. So, if item "C" was last created, then "B" and "A", options will be displayed in the following order: "C", "B" & "A".

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way of changing that order.  You can of course define sort and filter rules on the list view itself.  If you want to get creative you could add some sorting buttons to the list view page the re-load page with query string params that change the sort order.

Example add the following to your list view page URL:  `?SortField=Title&SortDir=Desc`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by modifying\creating views and changing the sort columns to meet your criteria.

[Manage Existing Views in SharePoint 2010](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/manage-existing-views-in-sharepoint-2010.html)